# Inherit from scikit-learn's LassoCV model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to extend scikit-learn's RidgeCV model using inheritance:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV, LassoCV

class Extended(RidgeCV):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Extended, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def example(self):
        print 'Foo'


x = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0], [30, 1]]
y = [2,4,6,8, 60]
model = Extended(alphas = [float(a)/1000.0 for a in range(1, 10000)])
model.fit(x,y)
print model.predict([[5,1]])
```

It worked perfectly fine, but when I tried to inherit from LassoCV, it yielded the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/so.py", line 14, in <module>
    model.fit(x,y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\coordinate_descent.py", line 1098, in fit
    path_params = self.get_params()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 214, in get_params
    for key in self._get_param_names():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 195, in _get_param_names
    % (cls, init_signature))
RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__ (no varargs). <class '__main__.Extended'> with constructor (<self>, *args, **kwargs) doesn't  follow this convention.
```

Can somebody explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want to make scikit-learn compatible model, to use it further with available scikit-learn functional. If you do - you need to read this first:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator

Shortly: scikit-learn has many features like estimator cloning (clone() function), meta algorithms like `GridSearch`, `Pipeline`, Cross validation. And all these things have to be able to get values of fields inside of your estimator, and change value of these fields (For example `GridSearch` has to change parameters inside of your estimator before each evaluation), like parameter `alpha` in `SGDClassifier`. To change value of some parameter it has to know its name. To get names of all fields in every classifier method `get_params` from `BaseEstimator` class (Which you're inheriting implicitly) requires all parameters to be specified in `__init__` method of a class, because it's easy to introspect all parameter names of `__init__` method (Look at `BaseEstimator`, this is the class which throws this error).

So it just wants you to remove all varargs like

```
*args, **kwargs
```

from `__init__` signature. You have to list all parameters of your model in `__init__` signature, and initialise all internal fields of an object.

Here is example of `__init__` method of [SGDClassifier](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L548), which is inherited from `BaseSGDClassifier`:

```
def __init__(self, loss="hinge", penalty='l2', alpha=0.0001, l1_ratio=0.15,
             fit_intercept=True, n_iter=5, shuffle=True, verbose=0,
             epsilon=DEFAULT_EPSILON, n_jobs=1, random_state=None,
             learning_rate="optimal", eta0=0.0, power_t=0.5,
             class_weight=None, warm_start=False, average=False):
    super(SGDClassifier, self).__init__(
        loss=loss, penalty=penalty, alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio,
        fit_intercept=fit_intercept, n_iter=n_iter, shuffle=shuffle,
        verbose=verbose, epsilon=epsilon, n_jobs=n_jobs,
        random_state=random_state, learning_rate=learning_rate, eta0=eta0,
        power_t=power_t, class_weight=class_weight, warm_start=warm_start, average=average)
```

Comment: I was hopimg that there was a more elegant solution, but apparently, this is the easiest. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still believe that There must be a better way! At least devs recognize this as  a problem: "Refactor BaseEstimator.get_params so that client code has access to the parent class' init" https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13555

Answer (score 0):

If you're wrapping another model, instead of manually defining all the parameters, define a `set_params` method that calls the wrapped model:

```
def set_params(self, **parameters):
    self.model.set_params(**parameters)
    return self
```

The current documentation is here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html

Note: you still can't pass *args to your init method, but you can pass **kwargs.

Also, depending on which scikit-learn feature or metalgorithm you're trying to use, you may have to set a few similar parameters.  Most should be listed in that documentation, though.